# google.script object in Javascript

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on google app script. There's a statement "google.script is a client-side JavaScript API" in [official document](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication)

However, I've search throughout internet and cannot find any document about "google.script" API.

I know there're several functions(or properties) such as

```
google.script.run
google.script.sandbox
google.script.host
```

because they appear in official examples.

But I want to know more details about this API.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you need. [Communicate with server functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication)